# Trying to understand read() in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, system-calls

I am trying to learn read() system call using the following code that reads from the stdin and outputs what was read to the stdout :

```
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int b=10;
char buff [b];

int n= read(0,buff,b);

write(1,buff,n);

printf("%d \n",n);


}
```

As it is clear the max. bytes to be read is 10. So I have tried the following scenarios :

1. I have entered just two characters, what I got was :

   AA

   AA

   3

I have entered two As and then the write() has printed them to me in the second line. In the third line I am printing the returned value by read() ( see the code ) and according to my understanding, the read() should returns the number of bytes that was read. So I was expected it to be 2 since I have input only two As, why I got here 3 instead ??

2. In this scenario, I have input 11 As ( exceeding the max. bytes to read , which are 10 bytes) :

   AAAAAAAAAAA

   AAAAAAAAAA10
   adam@adam-VirtualBox:~/La4$ A

   A: command not found

As you can see I wrote the 11 As in the first line , however, what was wrote by the write() is `AAAAAAAAAA10`only 10 As were wrote ( since I the number of bytes to write passed to the write() was 10), but what is `10`in the end ? Also,  `A: command not found` occurred because I have passed 10 bytes only to be read to the read() system call and it has rejected the 11th A , is that correct ?

Comment: In the first case the function also reads the new line character '\n'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have entered just two characters… So I was expected it to be 2 since I have input only two As, why I got here 3 instead ??

You do not enter characters. You press keys on a keyboard. The hardware and software translate key presses into characters. You pressed A, A, and Return or Enter. The computer translated those into an A character, an A character, and a newline character.

> In this scenario, I have input 11 As…

Pressing A eleven times and then pressing Return or Enter resulted in eleven A characters and a newline character in the terminal’s input buffer. Your program read ten of them, because that is all you told the `read` call to read. Then your program ended, which left an A character and a newline character in the input buffer. After your program ended, the command-line shell resumed running. It tried to read a command, and it was given the two characters in the input buffer, the A and the newline. It attempted to interpret that as a command, but there is no A command to run, so the command-line shell gave you an error message.

Comment: Thank you so much ! But what about the "10" in the second case? Are they garbage values ? if so, why I got them ?

Comment: @AAA: What question is there about the “10”? You asked for ten characters, you got ten characters, and your program printed “10” for the number of characters. Are you wondering why it is on the same line as the A characters? That is because you printed ten A characters with no newline character after them, so there is no new line after them. The program did exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: I was expecting it to be 11 because I wrote 11 As, but it wrote 10.

Comment: @AAA: You pressed the A key 11 times and 11 A characters were generated. Your program read ten of them because you told it to read ten. `read(0,buff,b);` means “Attempt to read `b` characters,” not “Attempt to read as many characters as you can.” Then your program wrote the ten characters it read.